# "No module named optimizers.PSO"

Tags: python-import

I am trying to run a python file called: "optimizer.py"

".py". Such file has several "import" lines, the first one being:

```
  import optimizers.PSO as pso
```

on the same folder where ""optimizer.py" lives, there is a folder called "optimizers", where inside there are the many files mentioned in the imports, including the "PSO.py"

When I try to run the optimizer.py file, which the README.md mentions being the main file, all I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "optimizer.py", line 8, in <module>
     import optimizers.PSO as pso
ImportError: No module named optimizers.PSO
```

What can I be doing wrong? Perhaps is not my fault?

Fell free to ask for more info and thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

Try copy the PSO.py to the folder of your main python file (folder of optimizer.py). then use `import PSO as PSO`.